# Indented JSON From Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, entity-framework

I have spent the last couple of days trying to read up and test a variety of methods for taking a property(column) in an entity within entity framework and retrieving an average from it that I then pass to JSON. I have gotten close a few times but always failed. Finally when I have the JSON I want to return it in an indented format to use in a JQuery visualization library.

My Controller is here:

```
    public virtual JsonResult GetData()
    {
        var result = new FactSurveryResultsQueries().GetAverages();
        return new JsonResult { JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet, Data = result };
    }
```

Here is my View Model:

```
namespace Provider.Models
{
    public class FactSurveyResultsViewModel //: BaseGraphViewModel
    {
        public FactSurveyResultsViewModel() { }
        //public List<KPIUserControl> customerSatisfactionChart = new List<KPIUserControl>();
        ////public List<string> customerSatisfactionChart = new List<string>();
        //public Dictionary<string, decimal> a { get; set; }
        public double? EaseRequestingHelp { get; set; }
        public double? TimeReachQualifiedTech { get; set; }
        public double? TimeProvideSolution { get; set; }
        public double? CompletenessOfSolution { get; set; }
        public double? TechAbilityProdKnowledge { get; set; }
        public double? HowWellKeptInformed { get; set; }
        public double? OverallServiceOpinion { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Finally this is my current iteration to retrieve just one property and average it although this is currently null.

```
namespace Provider.Queries
{
    public class FactSurveryResultsQueries
    {
        public FactSurveyResultsViewModel GetAverages()
        {
            var result = new FactSurveyResultsViewModel();
            using (var db = new ATSNavigatorDBEntities())
            {
                var thing =
                    from p in db.Fact_SurveyResults
                    group p by 1 into a
                    select new FactSurveyResultsViewModel { EaseRequestingHelp = a.Average(p.EaseRequestingHelp)};
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody point me towards retrieving one property and having it accessible from my controller as indented JSON so I can consume it and then I can replicate this for other properties? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Json.NET to serialize .NET objects into JSON. It has a formatting option that produces indented JSON.

You can install Json.NET via NuGet from within Visual Studio. Once you have installed it, you can serialize via `JsonConvert.SerializeObject()` method.